# what is advantage of super dev mode in gwt

Tags: gwt

I read Super Dev mode [article](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) in gwt.  I want to know why superdev mode in gwt2.5.

In article it says `Super Dev Mode replaces the internals of Dev Mode with a different approach that works better in modern browsers.` I can't understand it.

what is the advantage of super dev mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SuperDevMode provides incremental compilation to JavaScript, and therefore doesn't require a browser plugin. That means SuperDevMode works in **all** browsers on **all** platforms (including your mobile phone!), when "classic" DevMode currently works only in Internet Explorer on desktop Windows (more or less; you can still use a year-old version of Firefox, or a 6-months-old version of Chromium)

Comment: Thanks, It means even my browser don't have plugin, even it will allow me to development. this is help full in development mode only. There is no relation of what we do compilation to create war for production. am I right?

Comment: That's correct NFE. Super Development Mode is for development, not production. With that said, the latest version of the GWT compiler continues to deliver even better compiled size and performance, so even if you don't use this, try to always stay on the latest.

Comment: I am able to run superdev mode successfully. is every time I have to compile whole application on one change of development through clicking on `Dev Mode On` button?

Answer (score 0):

Super dev is still in its infancy. Yes in the end the idea from a browser supported debug sessions is great, but right now there's only a Java source pointer which uses the source map to follow the Javascript code... Therefore, no more field inspection etc while debugging...

If you do not mind looking at Javascript code, it works very well... Eventually it's better to look at the real Javascript code (next to the Java code) to see whats **really** happening 'down there' (most embedded IDE's operate in this manner). But you can also call this a step back as the previous dev-mode offered more debug services.